# How to create my custom class in Android?

Tags: java, class, byte, bit

I always create different classes in Android for example to call diferent Activities but now I would like to create a class to test a bit in a byte. I have created a simple method to do this, so I can do:

```
if(bitTest(my_byte,7)){
   ...
}
```

to test bit 7 of my_byte, but I would like to do something like:

```
if(my_byte.bitTest(7)){
   ...
}
```

How can I do this? Because I cannot modify what is inside byte class.

Comment: I don't think you can extend java primitve types.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either do what Sword22 suggests, or write a class that encapsulates a byte without actually extending Byte. You can have keep your methods for modifying the byte here too.

```
class Bits {
  private byte value;

  public Bits() { this(0x0); }
  public Bits(byte initial) { value = initial; }

  public boolean isSet(int bit) {
    return (value & (1<<bit)) != 0;
  }

  public void set(int bit) { /* ... */ }
  public void unset(int bit) { /* ... */ }

  public byte toByte() { return value; }
}
```

Also make sure that you actually need a primitive `byte`, or if you could use something like `BitSet` or even `EnumSet` to store your set of flags.

Comment: Nice idea but i am having the same error on extends Byte: "The type Bits cannot subclass the final class Byte" :/ Do you know why ? I already imported java.lang.Byte

Comment: Whoops, I didn't mean to make it extend Byte, it doesn't need to extend anything. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Byte is a finite class you can't do that.

What you can do (for example) is to make a new Byte class (ie: Byte2) use inheritance and implement bitTest in Byte2.

It will be something like this :

```
Public Class Byte2 extends Byte {
    (...)
    Public boolean bitTest(int i) {

    }
}
```

And declare all your "Byte"s with Byte2.

EDIT : See comments.

Comment: I tried that before but i get an error. My class is: 'class myByte extends Byte' and i get the error 'The type myByte cannot subclass the final class Byte' :/

Comment: My bad it's late and I wasn't thinking. You cannot extend the way I wrote it, but you could copy the Byte implementation from the JDK src to make you new MyByte class. The fact that the class is final not only prevent extension but also inheritance.

Comment: And another possibilty (i just thought of that) is to make a new class like MyByte that contains a Byte and acces to that Byte with bitTest(Byte thatByte, int i) inside of a MyByte method that you can call with MyByte.bitTest. But you'll have to rethink of all the the methods you use on Byte and reimplement them the correct way. If you want more details just ask.

Comment: Yeah, I figured just after typing it, didn't see your answer. :p